# Sharing variables from webpage with native file system

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-applications, cookies

I need to have a one way communication from web browser to a locally running native application.

I am working on a web based medical records system.
When the doctor opens a chart in a web browser, he is interacting with the patient.
One of the things he does it takes a photo (regular dslr with a eyefi card).
I have a local native app (file watcher), intercept the image coming from the eyefi BUT I would like to automatically rename the picture and store it in a correct folder. All I need to do this is to "know" what patient is currently being displayed in the web browser.

I was thinking of ways to do this but am hitting the wall.
I was considering having the native app 1. Read a cookie, 2. Read the title of the web browser window,  ...

I need to somehow deduce what patient is currently being worked on via the web app.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions without code are commonly hard to understnad

Comment: cookies can hop around. if your OS is locked down, title is a decently reliable way of doing this. you can also launch an app from the web page that sets the current user in some sort of a text file; window.open a custom MIME type and memorize the opening app the first time the save/open download box appears.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible and even if possible it's not a good way to do it.
I recommend having a web-service and call that web-serive/api from the webpage using AJAX.

The web-service is responsible for informing your application. For example, it can store the received data into a database or file and the the application accesses that database/file to read needed data.

The web-service can be something like this:

```
http://example.com/getData?title="a title"&filename="filename.ext"
```

and it can be called from your JavaScript code like this:

```
var aTitle, aFilename;
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/getData?title=' + aTitle + '&filename='+ aFilename +'
});
```